# Reading csv and convert data to editable form

Tags: php, html, csv, foreach

A question about csv parsing and foreach loop..

```
<?php

  //output
 Array   
(  

  [0] => Array
    (
        [company] => A Company
        [address] => A Address
        [telephone] => A Telephone
    )

  [1] => Array
    (
        [company] => B Company
        [address] => B Address
        [telephone] => B Telephone
    )

  [2] => Array
    (
        [company] => C Company
        [address] => C Address
        [telephone] => C Telephone
    )

)
?>

<table border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="3">
<tr>
    <?php foreach ($csv->titles as $value): ?>
    <th><?php echo $value; ?></th>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</tr>
<?php foreach ($csv->data as $key => $row): ?>
<tr>
    <?php foreach ($row as $value): ?>
    <td><input type="text" name="field[]" value="<?php echo $value; ?>" /></td>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</table>
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/QQBle.jpg

**I want to make a form with this variables**

First column input form name *company[]*

For second coloumn input form name *address[]*

Third coloumn  input form name *telephone[]*

**What can i do for this stuff?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change this line only:

```
<tr>
    <?php foreach ($row as $field => $value): ?>
    <td><input type="text" name="<?php echo $field; ?>[]" value="<?php echo $value; ?>" /></td>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</tr>
```

Comment: This makes rows equal
0 0 0
1 1 1
2 2 2
But i need coloumns equal

0 1 2
0 1 2
0 1 2